# Behaviour of the Cayley graph of a group when changing the generating set / Number of ends of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

**Introduction of terminology:** Let $G$ be an infinite group and let $S$ be a finite generating subset of $G$ that is symmetric, i.e. $x\in S$ implies $x^{-1}\in S$. Then the relation $g\sim g':\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}g'\in S$ is an equivalence relation on $G$. Consider the (undirected) graph which has $G$ as its set of vertices and an edge between $g$ and $g'$ iff $g\sim g'$. In this graph there exists a path from $g$ to $g'$ iff there exist $s_1,\ldots,s_n\in S$ such that $g'=gs_1\cdots s_n$. A subset of $G$ shall be called $S$-connected if the corresponding subgraph is connected. Since $S$ generates $G$, $G$ is $S$-connected.

For any finite subset $T$ of $G$, define $B_T^\infty$ to be the set of infinite $S$-connected components of $G-T$. Suppose now we have another symmetric finite generating subset $S'$ of $G$ such that $S\subset S'$. Define $B_T'^ \infty$ just like $B_T^\infty$ with $S'$ in place of $S$. Obviously, $S$-connected sets are also $S'$-connected.

---

**My question:** I want to prove that, if there is $T$ such that $|B_T^\infty|\geq 2$, there is $U$ (maybe a superset of $T$?) such that $|B_U'^\infty|\geq 2$ (and the same with $3$ instead of $2$).

---

**What I have tried:** Let $A,B$ be two distinct elements of $B_T^\infty$. The problem is that, though $A\cup B$ is not $S$-connected, it may well be $S'$ -connected. My strategy would be to successively enlarge $T$ in a way that all possible $S'$-paths from $A$ into $B$ are "cut off". My problem with this is that $A$ and $B$ are infinite, and it is not clear at all to me that all possible paths from $A$ into $B$ have to pass through a certain finite set. Even if we remove points from $A$ and $B$, these sets have to stay infinite and the problem persists.

---

**Background information:** This comes from an exercise in Bourbaki's Algebra which concerns itself with the notion of the *number of ends* of a group. For $T\subset T'$ a mapping $f_{TT'}$ is defined of $B_{T'}^\infty$ into $B_{T}^\infty$ mapping $Z'$ to the unique component of $G-T$ that contains $Z'$. The *set of ends* is defined as the inverse (projective) limit of the family $(B_T^\infty)_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}$ with respect to the mappings $f_{TT'}$, where $\mathfrak{T}$ is the set of finite subsets of $G$. This set of ends depends on $S$, but its cardinality (the *number of ends*) does not. That's exactly the part where I am stuck. I've already shown that the cardinality can only be $0$ (iff $G$ is finite), $1$, $2$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$. This can be translated into conditions on the sets $B_T^\infty$. For example, the set of ends has exactly two elements iff all of the $B_T^\infty$ have at least one element, some have two, and none have three.

I've seen the term *number of ends* in the literature, but never defined in this particular way (at least I couldn't detect any connection). So I've tried to make the question self-contained without this background information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea that I think works, but I'll leave the details to you. Express every generator of $S'$ as a word in $S$ and let $n$ be the maximum length of all such words. Now define $U'$ to be the set of vertices at distance at most $n$ from a vertex in $U$.

The idea is that if two vertices are in different components with respect to $S$ but in the same component with respect to $S'$, then there must be two such vertices connected by a single $S'$-edge. If you wrote this edge out as a word in $S$, then at least one of the vertices of this word (in the $S$-Cayley graph) would lie in $U$. By extending $U$ to $U'$ you would eliminate this edge and thereby prevent the two components getting connected.

Comment: That looks promising. I'll comment again, when I have worked out the details.